# Disable html <p> tag from refreshing after dynamically changing text from Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to show real time messages on a web application. I am using jQuery and Ajax to call a servlet to get response Text back.. it works fine but the targeting paragraph tag upon reload doesn't have the text used within the ajax method. How can I prevent the paragraph tag from refreshing its Text? the "**document.getElementById('MarkAlertResponse').innerHTML**" is the targeted paragraph tag. Thanks

Here's my code

[image]

Comment: Does $('#MarkAlertResponse').text(responsetext) not work?

Comment: It does work, the text gets updated accordingly. The problem is when I click on another tab on the web page, them come back to the home screen, the text is no longer there.

Comment: You say upon reload? It will always get refreshed because you reloaded the site.

Comment: When you navigate to different pages, you completely refresh your application on that site.

Comment: okay, makes sense, I just figured there was a way to have to that part static in a way. So I'm assuming that it cannot be done?

Comment: Not is this way. You could utilize localStorage API for this (even though that would be hacky :D)

Comment: Okay, I may look into that. Thanks!